# Quotient groups of "Abelian-times-compact", what are they called?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory

In what I am doing now this class of groups appears all the way: (Hausdorff) quotient groups of $A\times K$, where $A$ are locally compact abelian groups, and $K$ compact groups.

I wonder, if this class has a name. This would simplify my life.